# Extraer números hasta que se consigan dos con el mismo valor

Tags: javascript, jquery

El programa trata de ir extrayendo uno a uno los valores de un `array` de manera aleatoria. (Esa parte es la que adjunto).

Lo que necesitaría seria extraer valores hasta que dos se repitieran y además contar cuantos valores se han extraído en total hasta que se han repetido.

Si alguien me diera alguna idea se lo agradecería mucho.

```js
var cards = new Array(
    new Array("bastos", 1), new Array("bastos", 2), new Array("bastos", 3), new 
    Array("bastos", 4), new Array("bastos", 5), new Array("bastos", 6), new 
    Array("bastos", 7), new Array("bastos", 8), new Array("bastos", 9), new 
    Array("bastos", 10),
    );

function random_card(){
    if(cards.length >0 ){
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*cards.length);
        var palos = "<br>Palo: "+cards[rand][0]+"<br><br> Valor:";
     var numero = cards[rand][1];
        document.getElementById("div").innerHTML += palos;
       document.getElementById("div").innerHTML += numero;
        cards.splice(rand, 1);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
<button onclick="random_card();">Extraer</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que se me ocurriría es ir añadiendo en un `array` nuevo los valores del `array` principal que van saliendo aleatoriamente con cada clic al botón, luego de esto por medio de una variable que sirve de contador preguntamos si existe algún valor del `array` viejo que se repita en el `array` nuevo y en caso de ser así sabremos que ya hay un duplicado en la información extraída.

```js
var cards = new Array(
    new Array("bastos", 1), new Array("bastos", 2), new Array("bastos", 3), new 
    Array("bastos", 4), new Array("bastos", 5), new Array("bastos", 6), new 
    Array("bastos", 7), new Array("bastos", 8), new Array("bastos", 9), new 
    Array("bastos", 10),
    );
    
var cards_views_ids = Array();
var conteo = 0;

function random_card(){
    if(cards.length >0 ){
       conteo++;
    
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*cards.length);
        var palos = "<br>Palo: "+cards[rand][0]+"<br><br> Valor:";
     var numero = cards[rand][1];
        document.getElementById("div").innerHTML += palos;
       document.getElementById("div").innerHTML += numero;
        
        cards_views_ids.push(numero);
        
        var repetido = 0;
        
        cards_views_ids.forEach(function(dato){
            if (dato == numero){
                repetido++;
            }
        });
         
        if(repetido == 2){
            document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
            
            setTimeout(function(){
               alert('Se repitió el valor (Palo: ' + cards[rand][0] + ' - Valor: ' + cards[rand][1] +'). Se extrayeron ' + conteo + ' valores hasta encontrar el valor repetido.');
            }, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="random_card();">Extraer</button>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: Hola Bender! Muchísimas gracias era justo lo que necesitaba!! Mil gracias por tu tiempo de verdad!

Comment: Hola Bender no se si esto lo verás, es porque se me ha ocurrido si se podria añadir otro "jugador" para ver quien saca menos cartas, seria a través de otra funcion? Gracias!

Comment: @BelindaMoya a que te refieres con otro jugador? en este caso debes crear una nueva pregunta

Comment: Perfecto, gracias voy a realizarla con el codigo que me ayudaste y con lo que llevo hecho hasta ahora, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que buscas es algo asi:

```js
var cards = [ // asi se ve mejor el array
  ["bastos", 1],
  ["bastos", 2],
  ["bastos", 3],
  ["bastos", 4],
  ["bastos", 5],
  ["bastos", 6],
  ["bastos", 7],
  ["bastos", 8],
  ["bastos", 9],
  ["bastos", 10]
]
var valor_anterior = 0;
var total = 0;

function random_card() {
  if (cards.length > 0) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);
    var card = cards[rand]

    var numero = card[1];
    if (numero == valor_anterior) { // validamos si el valor anterior es igual al de ahora
      alert("ya no se pueden extraer mas valores");
      return;
    }
    total++ // sumamos el total de intentos
    var palos = "<br>Palo: " + card[0] + "<br><br> Valor:";
    var extraidos = "<br>Total Extraidos: " + total + "<br><br>";
    var anterior = "<br>Anterior: " + valor_anterior + "<br><br>";

    valor_anterior = numero

    document.getElementById("div").innerHTML += palos;
    document.getElementById("div").innerHTML += numero;
    document.getElementById("div").innerHTML += extraidos;
    document.getElementById("div").innerHTML += anterior;
    cards.splice(rand, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
<button onclick="random_card();">Extraer</button>
```

Solamente se le agrego un contador el cual se incrementa en cada intento y se agrego una variable llamada numero_anterior que permite comparar el valor actual con el anterior

Comment: Hola Mario! no era exactamente eso pero agregaré la variable numero_anterior, muchas gracias por tu tiempo de verdad!